# Grid Layout failing to align

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I am trying to achieve this, I want the `nav` and `header` tags to fill the left side.

[image]

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
body {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 2fr 5fr 3fr;
   grid-template-areas: 
       "header header"
       "nav main"
       "footer footer";
}
    
header {
    background: yellowgreen;
}
    
nav {
    background: lightblue;
}
    
main {
    background: aliceblue;
}
    
footer {
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

```html
<header>Banner</header>
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<main>Main content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: You've defined the grid areas **but** you haven't told the elements which area to be in.

Comment: @Paulie_D, don't know how? What do you mean?

Comment: Also you have defined three columns but only specify two columns in your areas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can try like this**

```css
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'header main main main  '
  'menu main main main  '
  'menu footer footer footer  ';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how you could define [`grid-area`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header main" "nav main" "nav footer";
}

body>header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

body>nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

body>main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

body>footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

```html
<header>Banner</header>
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<main>Main content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Islam, do you know how this can be made full, graphics? I made main 100vh, but that's way too much.

Comment: @JohnSmith answer edited. You need to take a look at how `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` work.